# Sending and Receiving Serialized Objects in Java - Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, client-server

(I know this can be done in RMI, but I need to do this using sockets since I found there could be some setup process if RMI methods used)

Please have a look at the simple Client-Server code at http://www.coderanch.com/t/205325/sockets/java/send-any-java-Object-through

In this program, the order two objects sent by SimpleServer are known by SimpleClient.

i.e: Server

`oos.writeObject(new testobject(1,"object from client")); 
  oos.writeObject(new String("another object from the client"));`

Client does the casting according to the order the object is received.But I want to avoid this nature and make client send any object at any time so the server should also be able to handle each object sent accordingly and return a result.

```
testobject to = (testobject)ois.readObject(); 
System.out.println(to.id);}  
System.out.println((String)ois.readObject());
```

Is there a way to "label" the objects being sent so that the action can be determined by a simple "if" statement in Server?

**OR**

is there a better way to use a ResultSet **returned by the Server** instead of my object serializing approach?

thanks in advance.

Thanks

Comment: The objects you read with ObjectInputStream already have the correct runtime type - casting doesn't change it. So in a way they're already "labelled", you can call `getClass()` or use `instanceof` on them and handle them according to that.

Comment: Don't use `new String("another object from the client")` its almost always pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readObject` will return an object in its proper class. if you need to have some branching logic based on that you can use `instanceof`:

```
Object newObj = stream.readObject();
if (newObj instanceof testobject) {
     doSomething((testobject) newObj);
} else if (newObj instanceof String) {
     doSomethingWithString((String) newObj);
} // etc.
```

As a rule, this is not recommended for all objects read from a stream. If you're going to use ObjectStreams to establish a protocol, you should document it and stick to it. That way, if one side sends incorrect data, you'll catch it more quickly on the other side.

However, in a scenario where at a given point in the protocol flow, it's *expected* that the client might be sending one of several different types of objects, then it might make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll be using such approach to implement an ATM simulator where user will send PIN, Card No from a Client program to a Server. Server will validate those data and if valid, show his Account details. I hope to send these Account Details as objects to the client. What's your idea about this?

Comment: I have an excellent server in Nigeria through which can handle this kind of traffic very efficiently